# How to make a connection to mysql using terminal mac osx?

Tags: mysql, terminal, phpmyadmin

I have downloaded mysql for mac and now I have opened it it terminal I am unsure of what the next step is.

For my website I use 123-reg.co.uk and I have a phpmyadmin account with them. Can I link that account server/username/password to the terminal below?

Or can I make a new account with localhost? How does this happen?

Below is what Is terminal says at the moment:

```
Last login: Wed Nov 30 10:57:14 on ttys000
Jamess-iMac:~ user$ /Users/user/Downloads/mysql-5.5.18-osx10.6-x86\ 
3/bin/mysql     ; exit;
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is ***
Server version: 5.5.18 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Thanks!

James

Comment: What do you want to *do* in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You're connected. You may want to `use databasename;` to be even more connected :)

But then you still have this problem of having to have a purpose for establishing connection.

Comment: I havent made a database yet, do I need to do that first? I just dont know how i enter into the terminal the password/username/host. Also do I have to upload the terminal or a file to my 123-reg.co.uk file manager?

Comment: Most of your questions do not make enough sense to me to answer, but to create database you may want to use `create database databasename;`

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'james
create database databasename' at line 1 

this is what i got?